# How to detect incompatible T-SQL syntax in VS DB project when targeting a lower version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Is it possible to cause the VS 2013 DB project compilation to spit out a warning (or ideally error) when it detects T-SQL logic that is using functionality only available past a certain SQL Server target version?

For example, we had logic using the `FORMAT` function, which requires SQL Server 2012 (or later). However, we still need to support SQL Server 2008.

Fortunately, we found this during a code review, but it could have easily made it to deployment. It would be much better to catch when developers are building.

Is there a way to detect/flag this situation when building?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set the target sql server version in your db project

Comment: I thought that would do it, but it didn't even flag it as a warning.  I even enabled analysis, to see if that might pick it up, but no luck.